# Should input adapters receive the domain model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

[This article](https://medium.com/@gushakov/clean-architecture-domain-entities-and-interface-adapters-4152b9ee22d2) on Medium addresses the scopes of the domain model in hexagonal architecture.

I have sketched the following generic hexagonal architecture:
[image]

On the one hand, the secondary/output adapter receives the domain model ("model" for short) and maps it to a DAO for persistence.

On the other hand, the primary/input adapter receives only the "ExposedModel" interface. This is then mapped to a DTO for the client. Why is this intermediate step needed? The output adapter also receives the complete model.